# Change the and to another word in biblothek

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

right now I am finishing my Ph.D. and want to change the author connetion such as *Foo and Bar (2001)* to *Foo und Bar (2001)* based on the fact that I am writing in German. However, I could not find the file in which I have to change the corresponding word. I am using jabref to build my bibtex file and I am using the following packages and styles:

```
\usepackage[round]{natbib}                     % Reference
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}                   % Style of Reference
```

While at the end I include the *bib* file such as:

```
\bibliography{Bibtex/Bibliothek.bib}
```

Any suggestion to the file I have to change is appreciated. Maybe I am just to stupid or searching in the wrong place */usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/*

Thanks in advance, 
Tobi

PS: I guess there is no need for a simple example because I am just searching for the file to change.

Comment: save plainnat.bst as gerplainnat.bst in your document folder. Open the file, search for `" and "` and replace all occurances by `" und "`.  Then use this as bibstyle. Or try to find a german version online. Or consider to use biblatex + biber instead of natbib + plainnat + bibtex, it has language support  built-in.

Comment: This is a duplicate of several earlier queries. Either follow the suggestion in Ulrike’s comment or the one in the link shown above, replacing `chicago` with `plainnat` where appropriate.

Comment: Thanks, I was just asking about the path. Stupid me, *plainnat.bst*. Found it now. How to change it was clear based on other questions. Thanks for the comment. By the way I was searching `find /usr/ -iname "plainnat"` which does not show up the file.

Comment: Just for all who come to this topic. Do not forget to `texhash` after you build the new bibstyle. Otherwise LaTeX does not recognize it. Thanks again @UlrikeFischer

Comment: @Tobi: I suggested to put the adjusted style in your document folder, there texhash is not necessary. Imho it is a "one-document-shot" and so a system wide installation is not really senseful. If you plan to use it more often you should check for other english words too. Beside this: you can find files in the texsystem with e.g. `kpsewhich plainnat.bst`.

Comment: It is my phd thesis and I want to keep all following documents in that way. Thus, in my particular case it is nice to have it system wide. However thanks for the hints.